# change value of a React input using javascript code in a chrome extension or console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

How to change react base input element using javaScript in an extension or in a chrome console debugger?

For example, i have put a sample React link here that has an input and submit button.
[https://codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/black-resonance-6okqm?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js)
When i change input with keyboard it submits the right value but when i change input value by console "javaScript" it submits the old value yet and it doesn't affect anything.

my js code:

```
 inp=document.getElementsByClassName("input")[0].value=5
 btn=document.getElementsByClassName("form-submit-button")[0]
 btn.click()
```

Comment: Please add the code that changes the value to your question, rather than just including a link to a code sandbox.

Comment: Try the deprecated document.execCommand, [example](/a/57900849).

Comment: Hello @wOxxOm, this example solved my problem. thank you so much 